# Conditional WHERE in SProc not working

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, null, conditional-statements, where-clause

Alrighty, so I am trying to create a stored procedure that contains a conditional WHERE clause. It uses named parameters that are initialized to NULL, and then determines whether to add them to the WHERE statement based on whether they are still null when its time to call the statement, or whether they have a value.

An example of the statement is:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE Sp_myconditionalproc (@xVariable VARCHAR(10) = NULL, 
                                       @yVariable VARCHAR(50) = NULL) 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      SELECT * 
      FROM   [MyDB].[dbo].[MYTABLE] 
      WHERE  X = CASE 
                   WHEN @xVariable <> NULL THEN @xVariable 
                   ELSE X 
                 END 
             AND Y = CASE 
                       WHEN @yVariable <> NULL THEN @yVariable 
                       ELSE Y 
                     END 
  END
```

and then it is called using

```
EXECUTE Sp_myconditionalproc 
  @xVariable = 'C', 
  @yVariable = 'AB';
```

For some reason, this does not return the results I am expecting. Instead of giving me results where xVariable is 'C', it gives me all results regardless of what xVariable is. Same with xVariable. Basically- returns the whole table regardless of what I put in there.

This is my first time trying something like this, so I probably have some huge gaping flaw in there, but I have no idea what it is. Could someone assist me in figuring out what I did wrong here and how to correct it, so that I can pass in only the variables I want to search by?

Thank you! =D

Comment: Side note: if this is for **SQL Server**, you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Outstanding advice. Thank you very much for that. I will avoid making that mistake in the future! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a misunderstanding of how NULL works.

Nothing equals or does not equal `NULL`, thus `@xVariable <> NULL` will always be false!

Try using either `ISNULL` in order to replace the `NULL` with another value or compare with `IS NULL`.
Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sp_myconditionalproc (@xVariable VARCHAR(10) = NULL, 
                                       @yVariable VARCHAR(50) = NULL) 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      SELECT * 
      FROM   [MyDB].[dbo].[MYTABLE] 
      WHERE  X = CASE 
                   WHEN @xVariable IS NOT NULL THEN @xVariable 
                   ELSE X 
                 END 
             AND Y = CASE 
                       WHEN @yVariable IS NOT NULL THEN @yVariable 
                       ELSE Y 
                     END 
  END
```

or this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sp_myconditionalproc (@xVariable VARCHAR(10) = NULL, 
                                       @yVariable VARCHAR(50) = NULL) 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      SELECT * 
      FROM   [MyDB].[dbo].[MYTABLE] 
      WHERE  X = Isnull(@xVariable, X) 
             AND Y = Isnull(@yVariable, Y) 
  END
```

Good Luck!

Comment: That did the trick! I can't believe I made that mistake. Thank you very much for your help =D